# Why are these HttpResponse methods not allowed in "asynchronous postback scenarios"?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, postback, httpresponse

I was reading to get some more information about the `HttpResponse` class. I came across an odd remark though on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx).

> The following methods of the HttpResponse class are supported only in
>   postback scenarios and not in [asynchronous postback scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28VS.90%29.aspx):
>
> ```
> BinaryWrite
> Clear
> ClearContent
> ClearHeaders
> Close
> End
> Flush
> TransmitFile
> Write
> WriteFile
> WriteSubstitution
> ```

What exactly does that mean? I rely very heavily on HttpResponse.Write in one of my projects. What exactly is an `asynchronous postback scenario`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An async postback occurs when you postback through something like an updatePanel.

The major difference in an async postback is in the render.

Your normal prerender and render logic will not be called.

Only a part of the Page is updated using javascript at the front end.

This means that you cannot return another document, change the http headers, etc.

Comment: Ah, so this only matters if I use UpdatePanels?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. You can do what updatePanel does, using custom controls too... It matters only for partial page updates.